# How to diagnose why git fetch is downloading so much?

Tags: git

I am investigating a git content server that's job is to sit between the real git server and users, and serve up content to users.  As part of this, it runs git fetch -prune origin every 5 minutes or so, along with some git packing/repacking.  Most of the time, the git fetches are rather tiny, but sometimes it will try to download a lot of content (more than seems reasonable for a once every 5 minute fetch).  This is how it looks most of the time:

```
"8/10/2023 10:24:04 PM +00:00: Fetch started",
"8/10/2023 10:24:37 PM +00:00: Receiving objects:   0% (1/419)   ",
"8/10/2023 10:25:36 PM +00:00: Fetch finished with exit code 0 in 92760ms."
```

But sometimes it will decide it needs to download like the entire repo pretty much:

```
"8/10/2023 10:27:16 PM +00:00: Receiving objects:  84% (4082235/4853943), 48.15 GiB | 6.97 MiB/s   "
```

I suspect either a file is being deleted, or a git pack/repack is causing this, or something  else.  The entire repo only takes 100GB, so downloading >50GB on a single incremental refresh is really strange.  And this seems to happen maybe 10+ times a week, so it is unlikely that users are responsible for churn.

Question is, what diagnostic steps can I take to determine what objects git thought it was missing and maybe why it was missing them?